# Will Data table sorting in C# and Order By sorting in SQL give the same result set?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to know whether the Order By clause on Sql server and Datatable sorting will order the records in the same manner. I have tried both and found the records are ordered in different way. Can anyone clarify?

```
SELECT Top 10000
'Link' As [Link],
ODST.ID AS [ID],
ODST.Type1 AS [Type 1],
ODST.Type2 AS [Type 2],

COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.Col1) AS [Col 1],
COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.ID) AS [Col 2],
......
......
COUNT(DISTINCT ODST.Col11) AS [Col 11],
SUM(ODST.Col12) AS [Col 12],
.....
.....
SUM([Col35]) AS [Col 35]
FROM ABC ODST
WHERE id in
(Select id from
(select Top 10000 count(*) AS Line, id from ABC WHERE 1=1 
group by id order by Line desc) t2) AND 1=1 
GROUP BY ODST.id, ODST.Type1, ODST.Type2
ORDER BY ODST.Type1, ODST.Type2
```

I have used order by in the above query
The table which i am querying has million of records in it. It yields a result in an order and it is very slow in running
so we have decided to move the sorting part to c#. We have commented out the Order By from this query and returning the result to c#.
Getting the result in Dataset and trying to sort based on 2 columns.

Sorting code is

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "[Type 1],[Type 2] ASC";
ds1.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable());
```

It sorts the result in a different order

so, over all, i want to know whether both ordering works in same way or the other?

Comment: Show your work please..

Comment: Show us your code which you have tried so far, please

Comment: collation and culture make for very potent things...

Comment: Maybe you could show us two values which appear in opposite order?

Comment: please show what you have tried till now??

Comment: Did you find any of this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Basically it does not.

The SQL implementation of `Order By` can differ, since it is another library that performs the sorting.

In your datatable, or any kind of ORM (like entity framework), there can be some differences, because the objects can be converted to `string`, `DateTime`, (etc.).

The sorting performed in the `.NET Framework` will be based on the data type, usually through a `IComparable` interface. This might differ from the logic implemented in SQL. Although suppliers of these frameworks will try to keep things consistent, differences may occur.

You can see this happening (if it isn't already 'fixed') with entity framework.

If you query the database for a `string` with a `.Contains` somewhere, it is converted to a 'LIKE' in sql, which is likely to be case insensitive.

Perform this operation to a in memory C# `List`, it is likely to be case sensitive and, hence, might produce a different result.